# Good resource for chrooting Apache2 on Debian

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, chroot

I need a better resource than [this](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ap-chroot-apache-env.en.html) or [this](http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/36331) on how to secure Apache2 using chroot on a Debian system. It seems most articles deal with Apache1. I tried to follow them and adapt to Apache2, but it only had bad results.

Comment: afaik, you do not secure apache by chrooting, but rather _try_ to contain the damage to the rest of the system in case of a breach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](http://www.howtoforge.com/chrooting-apache2-mod-chroot-debian-etch) seems like an easy way, but is it really secure?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) to do this for you very easily.

The documentation is [here](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.5.11/html-multipage/configuration-directives.html#N1049C).

Just install libapache-mod-security and add the following line to your apache.conf.

```
SecChrootDir /chroot
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running Debian, my advice would be to just use makejail, which creates old-style (external) jails with ease. I've used it many times without any trouble. I originally came up with the internal chroot idea implemented in ModSecurity (I am the author), which was subsequently implemented by mod_chroot and is now available in Apache itself. Had I known about makejail at the time, I would have never bothered with anything else. Having said that, the internal chroot facility is generally *very* easy to use if your requirements are not complex. It is very important to choose the correct directory structure. For example, put your jail in /chroot/opt/apache, then create a symlink /opt/apache to /chroot/opt/apache. (It's been a while since I chrooted the stock Debian Apache and I don't remember where exactly the Apache is installed at.) That would make the paths inside and outside the jail identical, which is critical.

Also, Chapter 2 of Apache Security (which I wrote) is available online from http://www.apachesecurity.net. It contains a detailed discussion about chroot and step-by-step instructions. It starts on page 40.

-- 
Ivan Ristić
[ModSecurity Handbook](https://www.feistyduck.com) & [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com)